# Radio-button example not working

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm learning Javascript and got stuck in this simple example. I'm able to see the blackcar image but when I click on checkbox for redcar it doesn't work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title></title>
    <style>
    #photo{
       float: left;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Which car do you like red or black?</h2>

      <div>
        <img src="images/blackcar.jpg" id="photo" alt="black car picture">

        <label><input type="radio" name="photoSelect" checked="checked" onclick="document.getElementById("photo").src='images/blackcar.jpg' " />Black Car</label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="photoSelect"  onclick="document.getElementById("photo").src='images/redcar.jpg' " />Red Car</label>
        <br />
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please help.

Comment: Look at the quotation marks. How should the browser know that `onclick` value is `document.getElementById("photo").src='images/redcar.jpg'` and not just `document.getElementById(` ? The second `"` terminates the value.

Comment: Why use XML-style markup in an HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

You're using quotes incorrectly.

Change:

```
document.getElementById("photo").src=...
```

To:

```
document.getElementById('photo').src=...
```

Comment: Yes , that was it . Thank you